# "The email address is badly formatted" Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication to log and signup on the app, but when i run the app and try to login i get this error on the console. If I signup, the app atomatically login and i am able to use the app.

I get the user data through a ngForm, here is the HTML code

```
<form fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input 
         type = "email" 
         matInput placeholder="Your email"
         ngModel 
         name="email"
         email required
         #emailInput="ngModel"
         >
         <mat-error *ngIf="!emailInput.hasError('required')">Email is invalid</mat-error>
         <mat-error *ngIf="emailInput.hasError('required')">Field must not be empty</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field hintLabel="Should be at least 6 characters long">
            <input 
            type = "password" 
            matInput placeholder="Your password" 
            ngModel 
            name="password"
            required
            minlength="6"
            #pwInput="ngModel">
        <mat-hint align ="end">{{ pwInput.value?.length }} / 6 </mat-hint>
        <mat-error>Must be at least 6 characters long</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <button type="submit" color="primary" mat-raised-button [disabled]="f.invalid">Login</button>
</form>
```

After i get the user data, the method onSubmit() is called.

```
onSubmit(){
this.authService.login({
  email: this.loginForm.value.email,
  password: this.loginForm.value.password
});
```

}

And here is the code on the authService for the method login()

```
login(authData: AuthData){
    this.afAuth.auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(authData.email, authData.password)
    .then( result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.authSuccessfuly();    
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Here is the error i get.

[image]

Comment: Add `console.log(this.loginForm.value.email)` to your `onSubmit()`, do you see what you expect to see? (also, `this.loginForm.email.value` maybe?)

Comment: I definitely don't see what i was expecting to see. Apparently, the ngForm is null. This is what i get on the console:
{email: "", password ""}
  email: ""
  password: ""

Comment: I'm not an angular expert but doesn't there have to be some form of data-binding? Your inputs' `NgModel` attributes don't have values.